# How to resolve this problem with RecycleView in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am trying to pass data from `Menu class` to `Container class` but I am having an exception `TypeError: Container.__init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'source' and 'mipmap'` I think the problel is not in Container class and `rv`.
My app is so simple but I am still stack in this touble. I

my main.py

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.list import TwoLineAvatarIconListItem
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.swiper import MDSwiper

class Container(TwoLineAvatarIconListItem):

    text = StringProperty()

class Menu(MDBoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.rv.data = [{'text': 'hello world'}]


class App(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        Builder.load_file('main.kv')
        return Menu()

App().run()
```

my main.kv

```
<Container>
    IcontLeftWidget:
        icon: 'home'
    IcontRightWidget:
        icon: 'home'

<Menu>
    rv: rv
    RecycleView:
        id: rv
        viewclass: 'Container'
        RecycleBoxLayout:
            default_size_hint: 1, None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `viewclass` of `Container` in your `kv` file is getting confused with a `Container` that is defined in `KivyMD`. The fix is to change the name of your `viewclass`. Try something like `MyContainer`. Also, your properties in the `Container` rule are miss-spelled (just remove the `t`).